# Form Block - add help text to form input

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm trying to add a 'help text' to the questions added by the Form block.
Something like [this](http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-blocks/creating-a-new-block-type/adding-help-to-blocks) but on the front-end part of the form.

For some reason its not saving the value or getting the value into the edit form. Even when I add it manually to the row it is not in the frontend output.

I made a custom form block / template with the additional changes to:

An extra table column 'helptext' in the db.xml. And updated the block.

```
<table name="btFormQuestions">
...
  <field name="helptext" type="text">
  <default value=""/>
</field>
...
</table>
```

An extra field on the editing form (normal and edit):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo $form->label('helptext', t('Help Text'))?>
  <?php echo $form->text('helptext', array('maxlength' => '255'))?>
</div>
```

Output it In the view.php

```
use \Application\Block\Form\MiniSurvey;
...
<?php  echo $question['helptext']; ?>
```

Added the extra code to auto.js,

```
addQuestion:
postStr += '&helptext=' + encodeURIComponent($('#helptext' + mode).val());
...
reloadQuestion:
$('#helptextEdit').val(jsonObj.helptext);
...
resetQuestion:
$('#helptext').val('');
```

mini-survey.php,

```
        $dataValues = array(
            intval($values['qsID']),
            trim($values['question']),
            trim($values['helptext']),
            $values['inputType'],
            $values['options'],
            intval($values['position']),
            $width,
            $height,
            intval($values['required']),
            $values['defaultDate'],
            intval($values['msqID']),
        );
        $sql = 'UPDATE btFormQuestions SET questionSetId=?, question=?, helptext=?, inputType=?, options=?, position=?, width=?, height=?, required=?, defaultDate=? WHERE msqID=? AND bID=0';
    } else {
        if (!isset($values['position'])) {
            $values['position'] = 1000;
        }
        if (!intval($values['msqID'])) {
            $values['msqID'] = intval($this->db->fetchColumn("SELECT MAX(msqID) FROM btFormQuestions") + 1);
        }
        $dataValues = array(
            $values['msqID'],
            intval($values['qsID']),
            trim($values['question']),
            trim($values['helptext']),
            $values['inputType'],
            $values['options'],
            intval($values['position']),
            intval($values['width']),
            intval($values['height']),
            intval($values['required']),
            $values['defaultDate'],
        );
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO btFormQuestions (msqID,questionSetId,question,helptext,inputType,options,position,width,height,required,defaultDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        }
$result = $this->db->executeQuery($sql, $dataValues);
```

Cleared cache and updated the block.

[Forum Post on Concrete5 with the changes](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/form-add-help-text-to-form-question)

---

**Solved:**
Got this working on a clean install of C5.

Small changes:

Added the original files form the concrete/blocks/form to the application folder (and changed the namespace)

db.xml (longtext was unnecessary)

```
<field name="helptext" type="text" size="65535"></field>
```

auto.js (Semicolon ; missing in the original concrete/block/form/auto.js (and thus the copy in application))

```
reloadQuestion: 
$('#editQuestionForm').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: If you check the database, is the new field there? Please post the relevant code here too, as in the c5 forum

Comment: Its added to the database.  print_r($question);  

Array ( [qID] => 295 [msqID] => 18 [bID] => 139 [questionSetId] => 1480941675 [question] => --Question-- [inputType] => checkboxlist [options] => --Options-- [position] => 0 [width] => 0 [height] => 0 [defaultDate] => [required] => 1 [helptext] => [input] => --Content-- [type] => checkboxlist [labelFor] => for="Question18" )

Even when i add the helptext value manually to the database but no value comes out.

Comment: When I add it manually to the right version of the Question (Forget about that) in the database the value is shown on the frontend and add/edit form. - **Saving it to the db with add/edit still not working.** It resets to Null